# iPhone - Moving a valid advert Offscreen

Tags: iphone, ios, ads

I have a banner Advert view (could be an `iAd` or another type) and It loads an advert.

Now after it has loaded, I might want to move it offscreen (for example when I load a complex UI, I dont want to confuse the user, so I hide the ad).

My question is, will the advert know its offscreen?  I.e. Will it stop updating its CPM and adjust advertising revenues accordingly, or will I be violating some kind of terms of service by pretending I am showing an advert when really its hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iAd `ADBannerView` will detect that it is not visible, so you can assume it will take appropriate action. There is no way to make a categorical statement about any generic advertising program.